# Sense8 Characters in Northern Hemisphere

Tags: plot-explanation, sense8

This is a 2-part question....

The [Sense8 Wiki](http://sense8.wikia.com/wiki/Sense8_Wiki) introduces the show with

> One gunshot, one death, one moment out of time that irrevocably links
>   eight minds in disparate parts of the world. Sense8 follows the story
>   of eight strangers across the world who are thrust into each other's
>   lives,...

The thing is, all of them live in the Northern Hemisphere...with the exception of Capheus who is JUST south of the equator (pretty much at it).  So I'm wondering, why are all 8 of them at or above the equator?  Why does this cluster not have some members that live in like, Argentina, or Australia, or South Africa?  As such, that's not really "across the world", is it...

So, from the creative aspect, why did the creators of the story make it so?

And exploring the reality aspect, it seems the consensus on the statistics is that [4 to 5 babies are born every second](https://www.google.com/search?client=opera&q=how%20many%20people%20around%20the%20world%20get%20born%20at%20the%20same%20moment&sourceid=opera&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8#q=how%20many%20people%20are%20born%20in%20a%20minute).  So the chances of 8 people being born at the same moment are very slim.  What are that chances, then, of all 8 of them being born in the northern hemisphere?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To answer the first part of the question, according to Wikipedia [only 10% of the Earth's population live in the Southern Hemisphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Southern_Hemisphere#Demographics). If you have 8 characters, that means that on average, .8 of them will be from the Southern Hemisphere. So I guess Capheus being just barely in the Southern Hemisphere covers that.

As for the second part of the question, keep in mind that 4 to 5 being born per second is an average. There will be peaks and valleys. It's entirely conceivable that 8 are born at the same time under such a scenario. It will be balanced out by none being born for a few seconds later on. And again, with 8, fewer than 1 would be expected to be born in the Southern Hemisphere (on average).